# application stopped loading static assets after the use of nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, nginx

I am trying to set up multiple proxies using nginx to various rails apps on one domain. These apps can be found in the domain as such: `example.com/app1`, `example.com/app2`.

After implementing this, `example.com/app1` stopped loading any static assets (ex. css images). Would anyone have an idea why this is so, and how to fix this?

The URLs generated by Rails reference the root URL: `/javascripts/filse.js`, which is clearly incorrect. It should instead be `/app1/path/to.asset`

Here's a portion of my server configuration:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    location /app1/ {
        root /www/app1/public;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        include proxy.conf;
    }
}
```

Comment: What URLs is the Rails instance generating for your assets? What HTTP response do you get when you load one of those assets by hand in a browser?

Comment: it is generating URLS that reference the root URL: "/javascripts/filse.js", which is clearly incorrect. It should instead be /app1/path/to.asset not path/to/asset